# ResultCode = -8

Tags: xml, visual-studio, go, post, postman

I have edited a code on VS, which only accepts XML as its parameter. In Postman, I have added an XML message in the body of the POST REQ with the post URL. My status is code: 200. However, I keep getting a result code= -8 as my methodResponse. I have searched online for possible causes for error -8, but got no where. Any Advice on what I should check?

I tried changing the data in the XML file many times, and I ensured all information in the code was met.

Comment: -8 Access denied 0 0

Comment: The -8 is an exception and not the status code.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.remoting.messaging.methodresponse?view=netframework-4.8.1&force_isolation=true&viewFallbackFrom=netstandard-2.1